# How to properly define a directives?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I see 2 syntax for define a directive in angular js.

The first way is :

```
angular.module("map-mcbjam", []);
angular.module("map-mcbjam", []).directive('map', function() { ...} )
```

The second way is :

```
angular.module("map-mcbjam", ['directives']);
angular.module('directives', []).directive('map', function() { ...} )
```

Can soemone know how to explain the differences between those 2 methods ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second way allows you to share the directive between several modules :

```js
angular.module("map-mcbjam", ['directives']);
angular.module("map2-mcbjam2", ['directives']);
angular.module("map3-mcbjam3", ['directives']);

angular.module('directives', []).directive('map', function() { ...} )
```

If you think your directive may be useful outside the module *map-mcbjam*, you should use the second way so that you can reuse it.